# Issue resampling using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas for the first time and have an issue resampling one column flyers['createdat']. Below is a link to the file.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pkhahu1k03moek1/LiveTweets1.csv

```
createdat
2014-09-21 02:54:40-05:00   2014-09-21 07:54:40
2014-09-21 02:54:40-05:00   2014-09-21 07:54:40
2014-09-21 02:59:57-05:00   2014-09-21 07:59:57
2014-09-21 02:59:58-05:00   2014-09-21 07:59:58
2014-09-21 02:59:58-05:00   2014-09-21 07:59:58
2014-09-21 03:00:00-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:00
2014-09-21 03:00:00-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:00
2014-09-21 03:00:01-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:01
2014-09-21 03:00:01-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:01
NaT                                         NaT
NaT                                         NaT
2014-09-21 03:00:01-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:01
2014-09-21 03:00:02-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:02
2014-09-21 03:00:02-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:02
2014-09-21 03:00:02-05:00   2014-09-21 08:00:02
```

I've tried:

```
flyers1m = flyers['createdat'].resample('1t', how='count')
```

However have only received: `Error: ValueError: month must be in 1..12`

Comment: Can you give output of `flyers1m.to_dict` and/or methods to get from csv to what you have ?

Comment: can you elaborate pls? I am able to read in the file for specific columns also. But resample is an issue.

Comment: I get a different error when trying to read in your data, which is probably as the Series/DataFrame I have is different from yours. If you get the output of `to_dict()` or the program you used to get the frame from the csv, then we can have the same frame you have - and reproduce/fix the error!

Comment: one more issue that I am facing is I am unable to read excel file from remote location. I am doing as below: import pandas as pd    
xl = pd.ExcelFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/oxx093ya4j6njrq/out.xls")  
Error: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/oxx093ya4j6njrq/out.xls'

I checked the path and the file is accessible in the browser. Kindly suggest